# Bokeh: grid of plots and aspect ratio

Tags: bokeh

I trying to make a grid a image and line plots, but the first image plot is stretched horizontally, apparently because of the width taken by the y-axis labels of the line plot on the second row.

Is there any way to prevent this?

```
# create an array of RGBA data
N = 20
img = np.empty((N, N), dtype=np.uint32)
view = img.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((N, N, 4))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        view[i, j, 0] = int(255 * i / N)
        view[i, j, 1] = 158
        view[i, j, 2] = int(255 * j / N)
        view[i, j, 3] = 255

#output_file("grid.html", )

p = figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=200, x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10))
p.image_rgba(image=[img], x=[0], y=[0], dw=[10], dh=[10])

p2 = figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=200, x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10))
p2.image_rgba(image=[img], x=[0], y=[0], dw=[10], dh=[10])

p3 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=200)
p3.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], np.array([6, 7, 2, 4, 5])*10000, line_width=2)
p3.xaxis.axis_label = f'Wavelength'
p3.yaxis.axis_label = f'Flux'

l = gridplot([
    [p, p2],
    [p3]
], sizing_mode='fixed')

show(l)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.0.2 there is not a direct way to control the inner frame dimensions. There is an [ongoing WIP Pull Request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/8085) to add this capability, and others, that will land in a 1.1 release.

In the mean time, you can:

- control the overall canvas width/height with `plot_width` and `plot_height`
- control the minimum padding around the inner from with `min_border`, `min_border_left`, etc.
- control the extent of axis ticks by controlling their rotation, formatting, or location

So, if you control the ticks (and account for any colorbar size, etc), and set appropriate min_border values that will not be exceeded, you can effectively exert control over the frame dimensions indirectly. I note that this is far from ideal, and look forward to the layout PR arriving.